# How can I add validations to print my own error message

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, validation

I am creating a customer model for my API and I've set my 'Name' and 'Email' fields as required. But when we leave those fields empty while creating a new customer, we got a built-in error from EF core , instead I want to show my own error message...how can I do that.

I've tried to add validations by code in my post method but It doesn't work...can anyone help me with that?...Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please  share your current `core snippet` for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do simple validation: **[Fluent Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/)**

```
public class UserRegisterValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserRegisterValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email address cannot be empty.");
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

When adding a new user

```
UserRegisterValidator v = new UserRegisterValidator();
ValidationResult result = v.Validate(usr);

if (!result.IsValid) return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, result.Errors); //Returns the specified error message
if (result.IsValid)
{
   //If there is no error, the necessary actions are here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use server side validation you can specify the error message in validation tags. For example:

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can also add some DetailsProvider to get better details when calling the api:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonValidationMetadataProvider());
}).AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Validation in front end has some other scenarios. Take a look at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0